# Elementary problems solved with Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Many times people come and ask me what Functional Analysis is used for and why it's interesting. Of course interest is a matter of taste, and I for one love the subject as it is. There are far reaching applications to Physics, PDE, other areas of analysis and other advanced subjects that I wouldn't be able to demonstrate say to a first or even second year undergraduate student.

What about examples that can be stated in very simple terms, and are somehow "familiar" to the broader audience? I am not aware of classical or definitive examples, so I wanted to ask:
**What are some (preferably mathematical) applications of Functional Analysis, that are as elementary as possible?**

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this question fits the format of the site - poll questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @T.Bongers Where should I post it then? I have seen several similar well received questions. Would slightly rephrasing the question help?

Comment: There are plenty of mathematical discussion forums around the internet, but [MSE is not one of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Historically, there were poll-based questions, but they frequently aren't seen as on-topic anymore.

Comment: @T.Bongers This is a math question and answer site with plenty of big lists full of open-ended ideas, and sure, these might not exactly fit the criteria of that link but if we discourage genuinely interesting questions then this site would become pretty dry, even boring. To be honest I don't believe that this is the kind of question which was intended to be suppressed in that link.

Comment: There is a related site on Mathematical Education

Answer (score 5):

From W.W. Sawyer's book A Path To Modern Mathematics: We seek  the solution to $f(x)=1+\int_0^x f(t)dt.$ We have $(I-\int)f(x)=1$ so $$f(x)=(I-\int\;)^{-1}(1)=$$ $$=(I+\int +\int \int +\int \int \int +...)(1).$$ Now $I(1)=1$ and $\int(1)=\int_0^x1dt=x$  so $\int \int (1)=\int_0^x(t)dt=x^2/2$ and $\int \int \int (1)=x^3/3!$ and so on . So $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n/n!.$

Sawyer writes that the response is often laughter.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite application: Image/video/sound compression and denoising (and more generally, signal processing).
From Fourier to Wavelet decomposition of signals, there is a plethora of techniques stemming from functional analysis for compressing and understanding signals. Examples:

- Fourier analysis is the basis for JPEG compression (everyone knows JPEG, right?).
- Wavelet and Fourier are both used in video compression.
- Fourier is used a lot in sound denoising and filtering.
- etc...

Answer (score 3):

A very important application is data compression, the [theory of wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) being particulary interesting here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of my favorites.

Suppose $f:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ is a function with the property that $f(nx) \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to} 0$, for every $x>0$. Then prove that $\lim_{a \to \infty} f(a) = 0$.

It seems to be an elementary problem but I don't know how to do it without Baire's Category Theorem. Specifically fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $U_n = \{ x>0 : k \ge n$ implies $|f(kx)|<\epsilon\}$. These are open and since $\bigcup_n U_n = [0,\infty)$, so by Baire some $U_n$ contains an open interval $[b,c]$. Then for $a \in \bigcup_{k\ge n} [kb,kc]$ it holds that $|f(a)|<\epsilon$. But $\bigcup_{k \ge n} [kb,kc]$ contains the open ray $[nb,\infty)\cap [\frac{b}{b-c},\infty)=[\max\{nb,\frac{b}{c-b}\},\infty).$